# JPanelの持つGraphicsを別クラスから更新したい

Tags: java, swing

初心者です、質問失礼します。
現在`java`の`swing`を使って、キー入力したら円が広がりながら消えていく、というパーティクルのようなアニメーションを作りたいと思っています。`JPanel`を継承した`SpreadCircle`でキー入力を監視して、入力されたら`Circle`をインスタンス化してアニメーション開始するのですが、その際`repaint()`を呼び出しているのにも関わらず画面に変化がありません。
なぜうまくアニメーションが表示されないのでしょうか？

また、`paintComponent`の仕組みがよくわかっていないため、`JPanel`を継承したクラス以外から`repaint()`や`g.fillOval()`のような`Graphics`の情報を更新する方法がわかりません。
色々と考えて`Graphics2D`の変数や`SpreadCircle`の変数を`static`にして見たのですがうまくいきませんでした。もっとスマートに`Graphics`の更新(`JPanel`の`fillOval`や`repaint`等)を行う方法があれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Frame_of_SpreadCircle.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame_of_SpreadCircle{
    static SpreadCircle panel = new SpreadCircle();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SpreadCircle");

        frame.addKeyListener(panel);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

SpreadCircle.java

```
public class SpreadCircle extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    public static final int size = 50;
    public static Graphics2D g2;

    public SpreadCircle(){
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
        Circle circle = new Circle(size);
        circle.drawCircle();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2);
        g2.setRenderingHint(KEY_ANTIALIASING, VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ

    }
}
```

Circle.java

```
public class Circle implements ActionListener  {
    int x;
    int y;
    int l;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int alpha = 100;
    int time = 0;
    Timer timer = new Timer(60,this);
    Color color ;

    public Circle(int w) {
        l = w;
        x = (int) (Math.random() * 300);
        y = (int) (Math.random() * 200);

        a = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        b = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        c = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        color = new Color(a,b,c,alpha);

        timer.start();
    }

    public void drawCircle() {
        SpreadCircle.g2.setColor(color);
        SpreadCircle.g2.fillOval(x, y, l, l);
        Frame_of_SpreadCircle.panel.repaint();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
        if(time < 10) {
            l += 3;
            alpha -= 10;

            drawCircle();
            Frame_of_SpreadCircle.panel.repaint();
        }else {
            SpreadCircle.g2.dispose();
            timer.stop();
        }
        time++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、 paintComponent(Graphics g) で渡された Graphics オブジェクトを保存しておいて、paintComponent(Graphics g) を抜けた後に、呼び出してはいけません。ほかのクラスに描画処理を委譲したい場合は paintComponent() から Graphics オブジェクトを渡してメソッドを呼び出しましょう。

- timer は Circle の状態(アニメーションのフレーム)を更新して repaint() を呼び出す
- Circle のアニメーション処理が終わったら timer を停止
- repaint() の呼び出しにより paintComponent(Graphics g)が呼び出される
- paintComponent(Graphics g) から Circle#drawCircle(Graphics2D g2) が呼び出される

大分いじったため期待する動作とは異なるかもしれませんが、可能な限り原型を残して修正してみた結果を以下に示します。

FrameOfSpreadCircle.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FrameOfSpreadCircle {

    static SpreadCirclePanel panel = new SpreadCirclePanel();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SpreadCircle");

        frame.addKeyListener(panel);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

SpreadCirclePanel.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SpreadCirclePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    public static final int CIRCLE_SIZE = 50;
    private Circle circle;
    private final Timer timer;

    public SpreadCirclePanel() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        timer = new Timer(60, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (circle == null) {
            circle = new Circle(CIRCLE_SIZE);
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2);

        // アンチエイリアスを有効に設定
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        if (circle != null) {
            circle.drawCircle(g2); // 円を描画
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (circle != null) {
            circle.updateCircle();
            if (circle.isEnd()) {
                timer.stop();
                circle = null;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

Circle.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Circle {

    int centerX, centerY;
    int l;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int alpha = 100;
    int time = 0;

    public Circle(int w) {
        l = w;
        centerX = (int) (Math.random() * 300);
        centerY = (int) (Math.random() * 200);

        a = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        b = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        c = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    }

    public void updateCircle() {
        if (time < 10) {
            l += 3;
            alpha -= 10;
            time++;
        }
    }

    public void drawCircle(Graphics2D g2) {
        Color color = new Color(a, b, c, alpha);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fillOval(centerX - l/2, centerY - l/2, l, l);
    }

    public boolean isEnd() {
        return time >= 10;
    }
}
```